# getting instance of taskOptions google awt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

hi i want to add a item in a queue that should be processed after 15 days or some defined time, so for this i need to apply the method **countdownMillis()** on the instance of TaskOption.
now please tell me how i can do that and add the item in push queue.
thanks

Comment: What are you confused about? You've just described exactly how to specify that task execution should be delayed.

Comment: i am not able to apply this method on my task. i just want to delay my task for some specified seconds( sec ). i am new and i am feeling trouble to do this

Comment: actually google says that i can manupulate various parameter of task, but how i get the instance of `taskOption` is a problem for me, as google has not specified it.

Comment: You create a `TaskOptions` instance by using `TaskOptions.Builder`.